# What is the correct tense after "May I know"?

Tags: grammar

Which of the following is grammatically correct?

1. May I know how you solve it?
2. May I know how did you solve it?
3. May I know how you solved it?

Comment: #2 and #3 are precisely equivalent, except that native speakers normally invert subject+verb in utterances that are essentially "questions", so #2 isn't very idiomatic compared to #3 (because you've introduced "do-support" and ignored that normal inversion). In practice, #1 would often be used with exactly the same meaning, but *in principle* it's asking something slightly different (it would be possible to ask with this exact phrasing even if you knew for certain that the addressee had ***never*** solved it, which you ***can't*** do with #2 or #3, because they imply he ***has*** solved it).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Could you elaborate more on "invert subject+verb"? If I were to follow it, how would #2 become? I apologize in advance as English is not my first language.

Comment: "How did you solve it?" is a valid question. If you add a phrase for extra politeness (such as 'May I know', 'Could you tell me'), you need to change the question to a statement. You want to know the answer, not the question! "May I know how you _did_ solve it?"